# What case is `This_Variable`?

Tags: c#, variables, naming-conventions

I saw something like `This_Variable` in my colleague's code. The language is C#.

I know `ThisVariable` is PascalCase, `thisVariable` is camelCase and `this_variable` is snake_case. But I've never seen a stuff such as `This_Variable`. What is this case called?

Maybe Pasnake_Case?

Comment: `Pasnake_Case`. I love it!

Comment: looks for me more like Net_Py_Case...

Comment: Maybe Wrong_Case if it's not the one your company use

Comment: See these references: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Multiple-word_identifiers. Some people said "title snake case", "bumpy snake case" or "train snake case", but they're non-standard.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, it could also be `Mixed_Case_With_Underscores`. Appropriate name.

Comment: Does this question fit SO?